# Programmatically Set Up Azure Cloud Shell

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-shell

Is there a way to programmatically configure Azure Cloud Shell without having to launch it and have it create a new storage account and file share (or go manually configure it to use existing resources)?

I'd like to be able to have an Azure CLI script (or Terraform) create the storage account and file share for me and have Azure Cloud Shell detect these resources and use them so when the Cloud Shell button is clicked there is not configuration needed.

This is needed whenever a new account is created or the resource group that contains the Cloud Shell storage account is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I believe currently feature to programmatically configure Cloud Shell to detect and select particular storage account and file share is not supported. So I would recommend you to raise this as a feature request in [this](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/598699-azure-cloud-shell) Uservoice or feedback forum.

However, IF the actual use case and requirement is - " to access the Cloud Shell (https://shell.azure.com/) without configuration need or at least by configuring only one time per subscription (that may be done manually)", THEN [this](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/598699-azure-cloud-shell/suggestions/33497182-preconfigure-storage-account-used-by-azure-cloud-s) is the feature request for the same which is already raised in Uservoice or feedback forum. So if interested, I recommend you to upvote it and other features that are of interest.

In general, Azure feature or product team would check feasibility of a feature request, triage it, prioritize against existing feature backlog, add in roadmap as appropriate and would announce and/or update the related Azure document once a feature request is addressed.